# How do I pass data back and forth between viewcontrollers?

Tags: swift

I am building a restaurant app where I show a menu (MenuTableViewCell)in the form of a MenuTableView in MenuViewController. Each menu item has a "Add to Cart" button. When I add to cart, I use a delegate in the MenuTableViewCell to add the item to my CartItemsArray. This CartItemsArray is then passed via a segue to the shopping cart which is a CartViewController showing the selected items in the cart in the form of a CartTableView.

In the shopping cart, the user can update the quantity i.e. add or subtract. I am using a delegate to receive the addition or subtraction from the CartItemsCell and passing this via another delegate to the CartItemsArray in the MenuViewController. However, this last part i.e. the update of the CartItemsArray is not working. I can add a particular item as many times as I want and the quantity is updated; but in the shopping cart, any addition or subtraction is not reflected in the array. Which means once I close the cart and return, any changes I made in there is not saved.

This is a cell in my shopping cart:

```
protocol CartItemDelegate {

    func didTapAdd(itemQuantity: Int, itemName: String)
    func didTapSubtract(itemQuantity: Int, itemName: String)
}


class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var itemLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subtractButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var quantityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!

    var thisItem: CartItem!
    var delegate: CartItemDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

// Increase the quantity of the given item in the cart
    @IBAction func tapAdd(_ sender: UIButton) {
        thisItem.menuItemQuantity! += 1
        quantityLabel.text = "\(thisItem.menuItemQuantity ?? 1)"
        delegate?.didTapAdd(itemQuantity: thisItem.menuItemQuantity!, itemName: thisItem.menuItemName!)
    }

// Decrease the quantity of the given item in the cart
    @IBAction func tapSubtract(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if thisItem.menuItemQuantity != 0 {
            thisItem.menuItemQuantity! -= 1
        } else {
            thisItem.menuItemQuantity! = 0
        }
        quantityLabel.text = "\(thisItem.menuItemQuantity ?? 1)"
        delegate?.didTapSubtract(itemQuantity: thisItem.menuItemQuantity!, itemName: thisItem.menuItemName!)
    }

}
```

Here is the CartViewController:

```
protocol UpdateCartDelegate {

    func didUpdateCart(itemQuantity: Int, itemName: String)
}

class CartViewController: UIViewController{

    var delegate: UpdateCartDelegate?

    var cartItemArray = [CartItem]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        cartItemsTable.dataSource = self
        cartItemsTable.delegate = self


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}

extension CartViewController: CartItemDelegate {

    func didTapAdd(itemQuantity: Int, itemName: String) {
        if let index = cartItemArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.menuItemName == itemName}) {
            cartItemArray[index].menuItemQuantity! = itemQuantity
        }
        delegate?.didUpdateCart(itemQuantity: itemQuantity, itemName: itemName)
    }

    func didTapSubtract(itemQuantity: Int, itemName: String) {
        if let index = cartItemArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.menuItemName == itemName}) {
            cartItemArray[index].menuItemQuantity! = itemQuantity
        }
        delegate?.didUpdateCart(itemQuantity: itemQuantity, itemName: itemName)
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the MenuViewController:

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

    var dishItemArray = [DishItem]()
    var cartItemArray = [CartItem]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        loadMenu()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func loadMenu() {
        // Network call to get menu items
    }

    @IBAction func didTapCart(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "openCart", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let cartViewController = segue.destination as? CartViewController
        cartViewController?.cartItemArray = cartItemArray
    }

}

extension MenuViewController: DishItemDelegate {

// If menu item is not in the shopping cart then add it, otherwise increase quantity by 1
    func didTapAdd(dishItem: String) {

        var addedItem : CartItem

        if let index = cartItemArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.menuItemName == dishItem}) {
            cartItemArray[index].menuItemQuantity! += 1
        } else {
            addedItem = CartItem(menuItemQuantity: 1, menuItemName: dishItem)
            cartItemArray.append(addedItem)
        }
    }
}

extension MenuViewController: UpdateCartDelegate {
    func didUpdateCart(itemQuantity: Int, itemName: String) {
        if let index = cartItemArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.menuItemName == itemName}) {
            cartItemArray[index].menuItemQuantity! = itemQuantity
        }
    }
}
```

I excluded network calls and setting up the tableview code for clarity.

Comment: In `prepare segue` of "MenuViewController" try adding : `cartViewController.delegate = self`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a rookie mistake (I am new to Swift), I needed to add the self.delegate in the table view extension for the cart view controller.